# Attempt attach child that is not of type RNScreen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting this error in my application after recent upgrade from `react-navigation` v4 to v6.

```
Attempt attach child that is not of type RNScreen
```

Here is my Navigation for the application.

```
function switchNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="loginFlow">
        <Stack.Screen name="loginFlow" component={loginFlow} />
        <Stack.Screen name="mainFlow" component={mainFlow} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and was beyond confused on why this was happening. My problem was that I had installed Expo version 40. React Navigation documentation specifically explains in [Getting Started](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) that you must use expo version higher or equal to 41 at the time I am writing this. This fixed my issue so I would check this first and see if you have installed packages that don't work with React Navigation.

These are the minimum requirements (Taken from their site):

- react-native >= 0.63.0
- expo >= 41 (if you use Expo)
- typescript >= 4.1.0

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have 0.64.2 `react-native` and I am not using neither `expo` nor `typescript`. The error is still there.

Comment: Have you tried updating your dependencies?

Comment: Yes I have all the dependencies according to the documentation.